# Shared Folder Virtualbox and Mac

Tags: virtualbox

I've created a Shared folder in the Virtualbox options but it does not seem like it works. Did I forgot something? Maybe you guys can help me out.

I'm running macOS Sierra as a host and Whonix as a guest. I want to have a possible file transfer between these two.

Comment: Does it not show up in the network on the host OS ?

Comment: No it does not show up on macOS or Whonix. I really don't know what else to do.

Comment: Please clear up your question with whats host-, and whats guest-os.

Comment: I added more details.

Comment: I haven't tried in Whonix, but since it'd Debian-based it may be acting like my Ubuntu guest on macOS is - the shared folder is set to Auto-mount=true in the vbox settings for the VM, and it mounts with a slightly counterintuitive name (on macOS and in the settings, the name of the folder is displayed as 'share', but it mounts as /media/sf_share on Linux side - maybe that's SF for shared folder?). It's owned by root, and won't let me chown it to a user, which also not ideal, but I can sudo less a file in it and it works. Which makes it not useful for purposes, I will look at mounting dirs from